# Using two models in a sap.m.table for formatting a control

Tags: xml, sapui5

I have a master-detail template based app.

I have a table on a detail side:

```
<Table id="lineItemsList" width="auto" items="{DO_LINII}" updateFinished="onListUpdateFinished" noDataText="{i18n>detailLineItemTableNoDataText}" busyIndicatorDelay="{detailView>/lineItemTableDelay}" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
```

It shows elements of the "DO_LINII" model (but the model of detail view is "HEADER" model - header of the detail view).

Inside the last column of my table I have an Input field:

```
<Input id="__input0" value="{BETRG}" width="70%" description="PLN" type="Number"/>
```

It contains the value BETRG from model DO_LINII.

The problem is, enablement of this Input field have to be dependent on STATUS from another model ("HEADER" model). Of course, I mean STATUS of the selected item in a master view.

I've tried to format this field using this expression binding:

```
<Input id="__input0" value="{BETRG}" editable="{= ${HEADER/>STATUS} === 'N' || ${/HEADER/STATUS} === 'O' ? true : false }" width="70%" description="PLN" type="Number"/>
```

but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you say "DO_LINII" is the model name then the syntax of the binding expression  should be like this:

```
<Table 
    id="lineItemsList" 
    width="auto" 
    items="{DO_LINII>/}" 
    updateFinished="onListUpdateFinished"
    noDataText="{i18n>detailLineItemTableNoDataText}" 
    busyIndicatorDelay="{detailView>/lineItemTableDelay}" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">

</Table>
```

here the expression **{DO_LINII>/}** tells the runtime that model with name **DO_LINII** should be taken and then its root object (/) which is expected to be an array.

For status expression (in case you have a model with name **HEADER**) you should use this:

```
<Input 
        value="{BETRG}" 
        editable="{= ${HEADER>/STATUS} === 'N' || ${HEADER>/STATUS} === 'O' ? true : false }" 
        width="70%" 
        description="PLN" 
        type="Number"/>
```

See again that > sign in binding expression is used to delimit model name from the property name. So, this **{HEADER>/STATUS}** references property STATUS of the model HEADER.

Comment: After this change (from {DO_LINII>/} to {DO_LINII>/}) my table is empty :(

Comment: @B_kog You should get a basic understanding of common UI5 terms. A *model* usually has a *name*. If the name is an empty string, you do not need to use the name when binding, e. g. `{Attribute}`. If your model has a name, you need to use it when binding, e. g. `{modelName>Attribute}`. First sort out what models you actually have, then we can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Input id="__input0" value="{BETRG}" editable="{= ${HEADER>/STATUS} === 'N' || ${HEADER>/STATUS} === 'O' ? true : false }" width="70%" description="PLN" type="Number"/>
```

Try changing to this. Everything else should stay the same. It looks like you were trying to access the property of your model incorrectly.  Should be {MODELNAME>/PROPERTYNAME}